# Who is the killer

Tags: logical-deduction

A man was murdered in his office bathroom. Detective Troby found a paper with alphabets written as below from the pocket of the dead man's corpse.

```
 ____________________________
|                            |
|  abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz |
|                            |
 ----------------------------
```

Troby inspected the paper and arrested the murderer from the office within minutes. How?

Comment: Detective Troby was soon after dismissed from the force, because the suspects he arrested kept being released by the judge due to a complete lack of evidence.

Comment: @Gilles: Don't you read newspapers? The murderer Noel confessed during the interrogation and handed over the murder weapon, and other evidences to the inspector Troby. Judge sentenced Noel for lifetime imprisonment. Troby got promotion and now happily having a doughnut in his cabin :P

Comment: "Curse you for murdering me! With my dying breath, I will write out a long cryptic message that obliquely hints at you being the killer!"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

He had a colleague named "Noel", The only letter missing is "L" - No "L". Noel.

Comment: "Noelle" would also work here.

Comment: I agree with the answer, however it would have been a lot easier to write Noel than the alphabet

Comment: @Keltari Yes, but presumably the killer would've noticed _that_.